# google-auth-library: Refresh token not replaying request

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

While using Google's google-auth-library Node Module, my refresh token is not replaying requests correctly.

The message I receive in the err callback is:

```
Error: Invalid Credentials
```

I've seen other questions dealing with this issue, but the solutions presented in there did not solve my issue.

Details:

In the below code, assume the argument **googleAccessToken** to look like:

```
{
    "access_token": "AN ACCESS TOKEN",
    "refresh_token": "A REFRESH TOKEN"
}
```

A minimal version of my client:

```
exports.nextEvent = function (googleAccessToken, cb) {
    // Load client secrets from a local file.
    fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, clientSecretContent) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        authorize(JSON.parse(clientSecretContent), getNextEvent);
    });

  /**
   * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
   * given callback function.
   *
   * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
   * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
   */
    function authorize(clientCredentials, callback) {
        var clientSecret = clientCredentials.web.client_secret;
        var clientId = clientCredentials.web.client_id;
        var redirectUrl = clientCredentials.web.redirect_uris[0];
        var auth = new googleAuth();
        var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

        oauth2Client.setCredentials(googleAccessToken);
        callback(oauth2Client);
    }

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
     */
    function getNextEvent(auth) {
        var calendar = google.calendar('v3');
        calendar.events.list({
            auth: auth,
            calendarId: 'primary',
            timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
            maxResults: 10,
            singleEvents: true,
            orderBy: 'startTime'
          },
            function (err, response) {
                if(err){
                  console.error(err)
                }
                console.log("your next events are : " + response);
            }
        );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is your exact use case, but I am using [passport-google-oauth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-oauth2) to get the initial access and refresh tokens.

Then, I use [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) for the API requests.

```
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  access_token: 'ACCESS TOKEN HERE',
  refresh_token: 'REFRESH TOKEN HERE'
});
plus.people.get({ userId: 'me', auth: oauth2Client }, function(err, response) {
  // handle err and response 
});
```

The documentation mentions that when the access token is expired, oauth2Client will automatically renew it using the refresh token and then replay the request.

Well, that part didn't work for me and I would always get `Invalid Credentials`.

Try setting the `expiry_date` to a unix timestamp more than an hour in the past.

```
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  access_token: 'ACCESS TOKEN HERE',
  refresh_token: 'REFRESH TOKEN HERE'
  expiry_date: '1469787756005' // unix timestamp more than an hour in the past (access tokens expire after an hour)
});
plus.people.get({ userId: 'me', auth: oauth2Client }, function(err, response) {
  // handle err and response 
});
```

That worked for me!

Comment: Indeed! That's exactly how I handled it :)